# What happened to the hats?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

'Twas the season, but 'tis no more...

Cool, no worries, I had fun while it lasted, now it's time to get back to work.

But I just think it ended a bit too abruptly. Was this part of the plan?

Comment: Yes. Yes it was.

Comment: You could just edit a hat onto your avatar.

Answer (score 5):

Winter Bash ran until the 5th, and then, as [the site](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/), they were put back in their boxes. Not sure what sort of notice you expected, but they were meant to be a limited time thing, and thus are no more.

Comment: ...until 4th...

Comment: The Stack Exchange Team have [published a Blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/?cb=1) about some of the different hats and what it means moving forward.